# Scroll to page top having an anchor in form action

Tags: asp.net

I have a .net page with a scrollable Panel that hosts a calendar that has an anchor placed on the current month. The form action

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" action="horas_admin.aspx#today">
```

forces that the Panel scrolls down to display the current month within the panel. BUT it also causes that the Panel itself is displayed on top of the page (once the page content doesn't fit in one page), hiding those controls that are placed above the panel. Any attempt to scroll to the page top using JavaScript seems to be overruled by the form action.

The only scrolling I want to take place is the one that's going on in the Panel. The calendar data is loaded by a repeater that is nested inside the panel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by removing the form action and replacing it by the JavaScript String:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#today';", true);
```

That portion scrolls the content of the panel in the right position to display the part marked by the anchor, BUT also places the panel on page top. To adjust this, I scroll the hole page to the top of the page.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"ToTheTop", "ToTopOfPage();", true);

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ToTopOfPage() {window.scrollTo(0, 0);}  
</script>
```

Both JavaScript strings are to be executed on page PostBack